# How to link a Django model's property in HTML audio source tags?

Tags: python, django, audio, django-forms

I've managed to figure out this much thanks to the Django documentation and Stack Overflow of similar problems, but I can't seem to use song.audio as `src` in my html's `<source>` tags.

## The Goal:

Display a list of songs with a playable audio file. This is **only** uploaded from the admin/ page.

## My Problem:

When I inspect element, the `<source>`'s `src` prop appears to successfully point towards the audio file, but it does not load it as an actual playable 'thing' in the browser.

In Django runserver console, the output when clicking the audio player's 'play' button is nothing, but when the page loads it is `"GET /songs/media/song_qW9qTXh.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 2715`. **Moving the media directory into the songs/ directory**, the **output is still the same**.

Chrome inspect of the output of the following code:

[image: Image showing the chrome output of the code]

## My Stuff:

#### Folder Structure:

```
song-viewer/
| media/
| | song1.mp3
| | song1_w784FH21.mp3
| | song2.mp3
| | song2_r8JJfq0.mp3
|
| song-viewer/
| | __init__.py
| | settings.py
| | urls.py
| | views.py
|
| songs/
| | migrations/
| | templates/
| | | songs/
| | | | song_list.html
| | __init__.pyt
| | admin.py
| | apps.py
| | forms.py
| | models.py
| | urls.py
| | views.py
|
| static/
| | styles.css
| 
| templates/
| | base_layout.html
|
| manage.py
| README.md
| requirements.txt
```

#### song-viewer/settings.py:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = ''

"""
The above static works fine (am able to link CSS successfully).
However, the below does not. I have shotgunned several different
methods of doing this, including setting MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''), and hiding MEDIA_ROOT
"""
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

#### song-viewer/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('songs/', include('songs.urls')),
    path('', views.homepage)
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

#### song-viewer/views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    # return HttpResponse('Hello from Home!')
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

#### songs/templates/songs/song_list.html

```html
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Song List</h1>
    <div class="songs-container">
        {% for song in songs %}
            <div class="song">
                <h2><a href="{% url 'songs:detail' slug=song.slug %}">{{ song.title }}</a></h2>
                <p>{{ song.snippet }}</p>
                <p>{{ song.date }}</p>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="{{ song.audio }}" type="audio/mpeg" >
                    <!-- <source src="{{ song.audio }}" type="audio/mpeg" > NOTE: This gives same output--> 
                </audio>
                {{ song.audio }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

#### songs/forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select an audio file',
        help_text='Must be mp3 format'
    )
```

#### songs/models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.desc[:50] + ' ...'
```

#### songs/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'songs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.song_list, name="list"),
    path('<slug>/', views.song_detail, name="detail")
]
```

#### songs/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Song
from .forms import DocumentForm


def song_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Song(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('song_list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    songs_data = Song.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'songs/song_list.html', {'songs': songs_data, 'form': form})

def song_detail(request, slug):
    return HttpResponse(slug)
```

Comment: does the browser throw errors/warnings on page load. The code you posted looks ok.

Comment: @t.stv the only error in browser console is `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/songs/media/song_qW9qTXh.mp3 404 (Not Found)`, which is the *same* as the Django runserver output. This message is also the same regardless of if the media folder is or is not in the songs/ directory

Comment: try replacing the {{song.audio}} with {{song.audio.url}}

Comment: Same result `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/songs/media/song_qW9qTXh.mp3 404 (Not Found)` regardless of if media/ is in songs/

Comment: have you added the media_url and the media_root as Black-Xstar suggested below?

Comment: I've tried his solution, been alternating between the two with `='/media/'` and `=''` then reloading my Django page on each answer/comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running on development server. You can serve media files from MEDIA_ROOT using the django.views.static.serve() view.

**song-viewer/settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**song-viewer/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('songs/', include('songs.urls')),
    path('', views.homepage)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: With `MEDIA_ROOT='/media/'` and `MEDIA_URL=''`, that code block throws `Empty static prefix not permitted` at line 12. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bananabrann Try: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Comment: Oh alright, that at least changed the console output in Django. With `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `MEDIA_URL=''` it throws "Empty static prefix not permitted" on line 12. With `MEDIA_URL='/media/'`, it loads the page but console output is `"GET /media/media/song_qW9qTXh.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 1833`.

Comment: However, adding a folder media/, (so the path is `media/media/song_fji44f8`) it **does** load! Where is it grabbing that second "media" though?

Comment: @bananabrann maybe remove `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` ?

Comment: That did not, sound still successfully plays at media/media/. My CSS is also intact, which baffles me because I thought `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`was the only reason my CSS worked

Comment: Having `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')` with `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` works and draws from just media/ Woohoo! Should I be doing this though?

Comment: I saw your css file. You can simply put the `static` folder inside your app folder which is `songs` here: `songs/static/styles.css`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on what css goes where, and what you're calling "static" where. I thought the site's css should be in the root directory, in a directory called "static", serving to every app?

Comment: I didn't see your full code or I just miss something. I can go back later to check. But I am happy it is working. I modified my answer based on your comment for now.

Comment: @bananabrann It depends on how you want to serve your static (css) files.